# $T$ cyclic and $\mu_{T}(x) = p(x)^m $ where $p(x)$ irreducible $\Rightarrow $ T indecomposable

Tags: linear-algebra

> Definitions:

$\cdot \hspace{0.4mm} \mu_{T,v}$: unique monic polynomial of least degree contained in $\text{ann}(T,v)=\{f(x) \in \mathbb{F}[x]: f(T)(v)\}$.

$\cdot \hspace{0.4mm} \mu_{T}$: unique monic polynomial of least degree contained in $\text{ann}(T)=\{f(x) \in \mathbb{F}[x]: f(T)(v) \text{ for every } v \in V\}$.

Note: If $T$ is cyclic $\Longrightarrow \mu_{T,v}=\mu_{T}$.

$\cdot \hspace{0.4mm}$ $T$-cyclic subspace generated by $v$: $\langle T,v \rangle:=\{f(T)(v): f(x) \in \mathbb{F}[x]\}$

> $(\star)$ Theorem. Let $W$ be a $T$-invariant subspace of $V = \langle T,v \rangle$. Then there exists a vector $w \in W$ such that $W = \langle T,w \rangle$. If $g(x) = \mu_{T,w}(x),$ then $g(x)$ divides $f(x) = \mu_{T,v}(x)= \mu_T(x)$. Moreover, for each monic divisor $g(x)$ of $f(x)$, there is a unique $T$-invariant subspace $W$ of $V$ such that $\left.\mu_T\right|_{W}(x)=g(x)$.

We use the starred theorem to prove the following theorem:

> $(\bullet)$ Theorem. Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space and $T$ an operator on $V$. Assume $T$ is cyclic and $\mu_{T,v} = \mu_T(x)=p(x)^m$ where $p(x)$ is an irreducible polynomial and $m \in \mathbb{N}$. Then $T$ is indecomposable.

Proof. If $m=1$, then $T$ is irreducible, whence indecomposable. We may therefore assume $m > 1$. Let $v \in V$ such that $V = \langle T,v \rangle$. Set $u = p(T)^{m-1}(v).$ Then by a theorem in the text, $\mu_{T,u}=\dfrac{p(x)^m}{\gcd(p(x)^m, p(x)^{m-1})} = \dfrac{p(x)^m}{p(x)^{m-1}}=p(x)$ and $U = \langle T,u \rangle$ is irreducible (by a theorem in the text). Now suppose $W$ is a $T$-invariant subspace of $V$. Then by $(\star)$ there is a vector $w \in W$ such that $W = \langle T,w \rangle$ and $\mu_{T,w}$ divides $\mu_{T,v}=p(x)^m$. Now suppose $\mu_{T,w}=p(x)^k$ and set $y=p(T)^{k-1}(w).$ Then $\mu_{T,y}= \dfrac{p(x)^k}{\gcd(p(x)^k,p(x)^{k-1}(x))}=p(x)$.

I understand the proof up until this point, but then:

By $(\star)$, it follows that $\langle T,y \rangle = \langle T, u \rangle$ and therefore $U \subset W$.

Question: Why does $(\star) \Rightarrow \langle T ,y \rangle = \langle T,u \rangle \Rightarrow \langle T,u \rangle \subset W$? I'm having trouble seeing this.

Comment: The starred theorem implies that there exists unique invariant subspace corresponding to a monic divisor which is p in our case. Thus the corresponding subspace U and <T,y> are same.

Comment: @random123 Thanks